# Why is the "drinking milk" trope so prevalent in anime?

Tags: tropes

Repeatedly I see that people in animes drink milk, often after bathing. Females tend to say that it helps to grow their chest. Is that true? But also male characters sometimes drink it, like *Kurozuma Watarufrom*.

[image: Oishii~ milk]

<sub>Image from [thedreamingotaku](http://www.thedreamingotaku.com/2012/11/chuunibyou-demo-koi-ga-shitai-episode-5.html). *Sanae Dekomori* from **Chuunibyou Demo Koi Ga Shitai** in episode 5.</sub>

What is the meaning behind the drinking milk trope, what do people gain from it and why is it shown so often in anime?

Comment: It's healthy for you and builds bone structure. also stops you ending up like Edward Elric (who hates drinking milk)

Comment: This probably largely comes from the fact that, unlike in the USA or Canada, in Japan you can get milk from vending machines fairly reliably. It's a really common beverage, both in vanilla and flavored forms. (And since you mentioned bathing, I'll point out that public bath houses all have milk available either in the change room or lobby.)

Comment: This is such a bizarre question. Why do people drink milk? Why do people drink anything?

Comment: @senshin You are right! I edited my question. I hope it is better now...

Comment: @キルア and by `"both in vanilla and flavored forms"`, I suppose you mean `"unflavored and flavored"`, not `"vanilla-flavored and other-flavored"`, right?

Comment: @Mindwin Yes. Colloquial "vanilla" (unaltered).

Answer (score 16):

There's probably no one answer for why they drink milk *in general*, but as far as the bathing, it's considered a traditional drink in [Japanese public bath houses](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sent%C5%8D) after a soak:

> There is usually a refreshment cooler here where customers can self-serve and pay the attendant. Milk drinks are traditional favorites and sometimes there is ice cream.

Most places don't know how the tradition started but [it's been around for a long time](http://www.gjsentinel.com/blogs/west_meets_east/entry/japanese-baths-and-hot-springs) and some people say that milk drinks (not just plain milk but also milk+coffee) [taste particularly good after a hot bath](https://www.tsunagujapan.com/japans-bathing-culture-sento/).

Comment: Because to slow spoiling, milk tends to be cooled, and unlike plain water, it contains enough minerals to replace those lost in sweat.